# Security algorithm for application

Tags: c++, security

I've discovered in some application quite interesting security procedure.
List of security sensitive functions is stored in hashed/crypted state (in this case Ruby Block Cipher Mark 5). List of those entries is build with ID, size, hash key and pointer to area with code data).

runCryptedFunc finds this function, allocated memory for it, copy and uncrypt it, run and then cleans up.

In other placed I found similar case when bunch of functions are checked for modification by comparing stored HASH of them with currently run code. In case of debug breakpoints or patches - all code crashes.

My question:

How they gathered hashed/crypted functions content and placed it inside binary? Those date (for sure from security reasons) aren't loaded from file of elsewhere.

How the created HASHes from binary functions and placed it in binary?

Comment: So, where's the code?

Comment: basic question, please do your own reading on this topic. There are many "old" ( 200* year ) documents on this. Eg: http://sandmark.cs.arizona.edu/ginger_pubs_talks/re_trust06.pdf

Comment: @Najzero It may be a little broad in scope, but it's not a *basic* question. Have a look around stackoverflow, there are 100+ upvote questions about "How do I find the length of a list in python". In terms of difficulty, I think this is a fair question, and even doing one's own research requires a fair bit of knowing where to start.

Comment: @us2012 - yup I meant broad as "basic" (my typing-ahead fingers dont always think in english). I sometimes wonder how "new generations" (without the strange fetish to look into assembler code with 12 years age) will get the feel for those topics ( basics -> comfortable languages -> high languages ).

Comment: This security procedure  is quite nice. I would like to use it in protecting own applications.
For example - split few essentials functions outside app, first run of App will create Hardware/OS ID (i.e. Windows Product owner, organization, CPU ID, Graphic Card ID - all gathered and hashed to one string), use it to crypt those functions and return them to user.
Without license program won't work. You are completely unable to skip/ignore those functions as without them program fails.

This security procedure I found in ArmyBuilder program.

Comment: If your code knows how to decrypt and ever has the key, then you are fighting a losing battle against anyone trying to break your code.

Comment: Yes, your right. But security for most of time is about how much time and effort you need to spend to break this security.
@Najzero I found this problem during Reverse Engineering. But I didn't know how this whole problem is named. For that thank you.